# How to make GEO Point Class Parcelable or Serializable as I want to pass them using Intent

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, parcelable

I am using Cloud Firestore as my Database and in every document there is a Map named restaurant_info that has  as  it typically stores <"name","Name of The Restaurant">, <"Location",GEOPoint of the Restaurant> and some more  fields. The problem is the Geo Point class doesn't implement Parcelable or Serializable interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can solve this. The first one would be to add to your `Restaurant` class that implements the `Parcelable` interface:

```
class Restaurant implements Parcelable {}
```

And then override `writeToParcel()` method and create another constructor like this:

```
private GeoPoint geoPoint;

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeDouble(geoPoint.getLatitude());
    parcel.writeDouble(geoPoint.getLongitude());
}

public Restaurant(Parcel in) {
    Double lat = in.readDouble();
    Double lng = in.readDouble();
    geoPoint = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
}
```

The second approach would be to store the `lat` and `long` in your `Restaurant` class as double primitves and everytime you need a GeoPoint object, create it like this:

```
GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(restaurant.getLatitude(), restaurant.getLongitudeE6());
```

Comment: Thanks Alex it helped me a lot.